# TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am testing my `Service` using `httpBackend`. It is a simple `get` request that I want tested (response code) in this case. But I keep on getting the error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$httpBackend.expectGET('/api/something').response({})') in test/spec/services/requests.js (line 22)
        test/spec/services/requests.js:22:51
        Error: Unsatisfied requests: GET /api/something in /bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js (line 1812)
        verifyNoOutstandingExpectation@/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1812:74
        /test/spec/services/requests.js:28:48
```

This is the service:

```
angular.module('requestService', [])
  .factory('Request', ['$http', 'localConfig', 'Query', function($http, localConfig){
return {
      getRequest: function(fromDate, toDate) {
        return $http({
          url: '/api/something',
          method: "GET",
          params: {fromDate: fromDate,
                    toDate: toDate},
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
          }
        })
      }
     }
  }]);
```

This is how I am testing it:

```
describe('Service: Request', function () {
  var reqService, $httpBackend;
  beforeEach(module('webapp'));
  beforeEach(module('requestService'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(Request, _$httpBackend_){
    reqService = Request;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  }));

  it('should test the response to be 200', function(){
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/something').response({});
    $httpBackend.flush();
  });

  afterEach(function(){
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  })
});
```

**EDIT**

I made the change(as suggested) to my test:

```
it('should test the response to be 200', function(){
    console.log('service: ' + reqService);
    reqService.getRequest('2016-03-26', '2016-03-29');
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/something').respond({});
    $httpBackend.flush();
  });
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
 Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/something?fromDate=2016-03-26&toDate=2016-03-29
        Expected GET /api/something in /bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js (line 1403)
        $httpBackend@/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1403:90
        sendReq@/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11235:21
        serverRequest@/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10945:23
        processQueue@/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15552:30
        /bower_components/angular/angular.js:15568:39
        $eval@/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16820:28
        $digest@/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16636:36
        flush@/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1778:45
        /test/spec/services/requests.js:24:23
        Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest in bower_components/angular/angular.js (line 17178)
        beginPhase@/bower_components/angular/angular.js:17178:88
        $digest@//bower_components/angular/angular.js:16616:19
        verifyNoOutstandingExpectation@/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1810:45
        /test/spec/services/requests.js:29:48
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't called `getRequest` function of service, so ajax call never get called & that's why`expectGET` isn't got satiesfied & thrown `Error: Unsatisfied requests:` Error. Also fix typo of `response` to `respond`

```
it('should test the response to be 200', function(){
    //action
    reqService.getRequest();

    $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/something').respond({});
    $httpBackend.flush();
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggested solution, But I am still getting another error. I have made the edit..

Comment: could you create fiddle/plunkr?

Comment: @faizanjehangir see I asked you to have working plunkr. not just to copy and paste code inside a plunkr..

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to use [`respond()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#expectGET), not `response()`:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('/api/something').respond({});
```